# Powershell Script on Macbook returning errors

Tags: macos, powershell, web-scraping

Trying to run a PS script that scrapes a web page and exports a table to a .csv file. When I run it on my Windows desktop, there are no errors, but when I try running it on my macbook, I get the following errors:

> InvalidOperation: /users/luke/Downloads/NHLAdvStats.ps1:7 Line | 7 |
>   $table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -ski
>   … | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>
> InvalidOperation: /users/luke/Downloads/NHLAdvStats.ps1:14 Line | 14 |
>   $headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText |
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>
> InvalidOperation: /users/luke/Downloads/NHLAdvStats.ps1:21 Line | 21 |
>   $headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)]) |
>   Cannot index into a null array.
>
> InvalidOperation: /users/luke/Downloads/NHLAdvStats.ps1:21 Line | 21 |
>   $headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)]) |
>   Cannot index into a null array.
>
> InvalidOperation: /Users/luke/Downloads/NHLStats.ps1:9 Line | 9 |
>   $table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -ski
>   … | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>
> InvalidOperation: /Users/luke/Downloads/NHLStats.ps1:16 Line | 16 |
>   $headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText |
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

My code:

```
. /users/luke/Downloads/NHLAdvStats.ps1

$url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html"

#getting the data
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url

#grab the third table
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -skip 2 | Select -First 1


#get the rows of the Team Statistics table
$rows = $table.rows

#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText
$headers = $headers | % { if ($_ -eq "GF") { "GFPG" }  else { $_ }}

#count the number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TEAM header and replace any headers you want to change
$headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (we need to skip the header row) and create a custom object
$allData = @{}
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash[$headers[$j]] = $rowdata[$j]        
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
  $allData.Add($i, $objHash)
}

$out | Select TEAM,AvAge,GP,W,L,OL,PTS,PTS%,GFPG,GA,SOW,SOL,SRS,SOS,TG/G,EVGF,EVGA,PP,PPO,PP%,PPA,PPOA,PK%,SH,SHA,PIM/G,oPIM/G,S,S%,SA,SV%,SO -SkipLast 1 | Export-Csv -Path "/Users/luke/Downloads/$((Get-Date).ToString("'NHL Stats' yyyy-MM-dd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Second script:

```
$url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html"

#get the data
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url

#get the first table
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -skip 3 | Select -First 1


#get the rows
$rows = $table.rows

#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText
$headers = $headers | % { if ($_ -eq "xGF") { "xGFPG" }  else { $_ }}

#count number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TEAM header
$headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (we need to skip the header row) and create a custom object
$allData = @{}
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash[$headers[$j]] = $rowdata[$j]        
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
  $allData.Add($i, $objHash)
}

$out | Select TEAM,S%,SV%,PDO,CF,CA,CF%,FF,FA,FF%,xGFPG,xGA,aGF,aGA,axDiff,SCF,SCA,SCF%,HDF,HDA,HDF%,HDGF,HDC%,HDGA,HDCO% | Export-Csv -Path "/Users/luke/downloads/$((Get-Date).ToString("'NHL AdvStats' yyyy-MM-dd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I have never encountered these errors before, so I am a bit stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: my understanding is that `ParsedHtml` requires PoSh on windows since it uses  InternetExplorer to do the parsing. //// also, why do you have `powershell-4.0` listed in your tags? that does not run on macos.

Comment: What @Lee_Dailey said - the `ParsedHtml` property is only available in Windows PowerShell

Comment: @Lee_Dailey , is there an equivalent I can run on my macbook? Or is it a lost cause? Ideally I'd just like to web scrape these pages and export them to a .csv on my mac!

Comment: or @MathiasR.Jessen if you know of anything!

Comment: @jackrabbit - from what i can tell, there is no equivalent with ps6 or ps7. while the two web oriented cmdlets have been seriously improved in terms of speed and flexibility, the HTML parsing stuff is not part of that ... yet. my understanding is that you will need to either download and parse it yourself OR use something like selenium.